# Batch processing Acrobat Forms

Tags: pdf, forms, macros

I'm looking for a Windows app/process/whatever to batch export Acrobat PDF Forms to an Excel file. I've been searching for days and couldn't find any. Does someone has a link to a solution?

This is a fairly common task, I suppose.

App should do:

```
<INPUT FOLDER> -> <APPEND PDF FORM DATA TO EXCEL> -> <MOVE INPUT FILE>
```

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: To be clear, you are looking for something that will take the values from form fields in a PDF and add that data as a row to an Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Exact, but with batch processing, i.e.with no human intervention.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any great recommendations for you unless you are interested in building something like this. Would getting a CSV file that can be opened in Excel be close enough?